# NInjecting into a asp.net website httphandler

Tags: c#, asp.net, ninject, httphandler

I'm trying to inject a service into a HttpHandler i wrote. But all I'm getting is a Service with a null value.

I have created a small example to illustrate my problem using a normal asp.net website.

```
 public class MyHandler :IHttpHandler
{
    [Inject]
    public IHelloService HelloService { get; set; }

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        context.Response.Write(HelloService.Hello());
    }

    public bool IsReusable { get; private set; }
}
```

The Service

```
 public interface IHelloService
{
    string Hello();
}

public class HelloService : IHelloService
{
    public string Hello()
    {
        return string.Format("Hello, the time is now {0}", DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString());
    }
}
```

NinjectWebCommon.cs

```
private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
    {
        kernel.Bind<IHelloService>().To<HelloService>();
    }
```

And finally my web.config

```
<httpHandlers>
   <add verb="*" path="*.aspx" type="HttpHandlerTest.App_Code.MyHandler" />
</httpHandlers>
```

I can see that there is a `Ninject.Web.HttpHandlerBase`, but when I use that, I simple get an empty response back and it never hits `ProcessRequest`.

Just for the record, this is what the MyHandler looks like when using HttpHandlerBase

```
 public class MyHandler :Ninject.Web.HttpHandlerBase
{
    [Inject]
    public IHelloService HelloService { get; set; }

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        context.Response.Write(HelloService.Hello());
    }

    protected override void DoProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {

    }

    public override bool IsReusable { get { return true; } }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the solution to make it work. Modify the Myhandler.cs to this.

```
 public class MyHandler : Ninject.Web.HttpHandlerBase
{
    [Inject]
    public IHelloService HelloService { get; set; }

    protected override void DoProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        context.Response.Write(HelloService.Hello());
    }

    public override bool IsReusable { get { return true; } }
}
```